# How to execute code when authenticating with default providers?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm building a .net backend for my Azure Mobile Service.

I would like to execute code whenever someone authenticates with one of the default providers (i.e. Microsoft, Google, Facebook etc.).

Some examples of what I would like to do during authentication:

- Associate their MS/Google/FB Account ID with my own user accounts
- Add claims to the ServiceUser

To sum it up: is there any way to hook into the server side execution of MobileService.LoginAsync(provider) in a .net backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should look at the custom authentication feature of Mobile Services, which should be flexible enough for your use case: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/

You might also be interested in the new AAD B2C offering, which has a lot of features that might fit your scenario: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/active-directory-b2c/